# Opposite of being settled down?

Tags: antonyms

Settled down, in the context of someone is set in life where they are- happy with their job, their family, they have have a mortgage and a little dog and all that sort of thing.

Is there a word/two or three words, that means the opposite of this?

One that came to mind for me was wanderlust but this carries too strong a connotation of travel. People can be not settled down but still not so big on travelling- it might just be in their career or love life that they've yet to find equilibrium.

Conservative vs innovative perhaps is a better comparison? But thats saying because you're settled you can't be innovative. Many great scientists were i'm sure settled.

Maybe going more into reactive vs proactive? Though again there I think I may be putting too much of a negative spin on people who are settled. Maybe the people who are still bouncing around are doing so because of situations beyond their control (e.g. refugees).

Any clue about this dichotomy?

Comment: "restless" springs to mind

Comment: It seems to me that you are putting too much meaning into "being settled down", so that finding an opposite that fits all of it is not possible. Being settled down in my opinion does not imply being happy with the situation or even comfortable. It just means being bound to one place, usually by all those things mentioned, but not necessarily so.

Comment: *not (well-) settled* is the phrase that correctly and unambiguously conveys the intended meaning in the context. Why take chances just for brevity?

Comment: The other one, too many concepts, unrelated to each other, in the post. Looks like you are unable to express the thought directly. Take help if needed. Good Luck.

Comment: I'd post an answer to this question, but I'm too ***footloose and fancy free***. You ***can't tie me down***. I ***haven't got a care in the world***. In fact, I'm completely ***carefree***.

Comment: an alternative to *settled down* is *alternative* lifestyle.

Comment: Errr, I'm not sure using "alternative lifestyle" as the opposite of "settled down" wouldn't be misunderstood, @PhilSweet

Comment: _In transition_ might have some of the meaning you're looking for. _Unsettled_ is the obvious opposite, and _unresolved_ (as in "unresolved issues") might also be applicable.

Answer (score 6):

***Footloose*** (Able to do as one pleases owing to a lack of responsibilities or commitments; now esp., free to relocate or travel without concern or constraints. OED)

*and fancy free*. (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fancy-free)

Comment: That has to be the answer, a great word.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps by focusing on the settled-down person's state of mind, you might find some good antonyms.

A settled-down person is

> - content
> - free of anxiety
> - untroubled and unperturbed
> - rooted
> - at ease and relaxed
> - comfortable, cosy, characterized by *Gemütlichkeit*
> - peaceful, tranquil

Antonyms for the above descriptors could include

> - discontented, restless
> - anxious, worried, preoccupied, nervous, agitated
> - troubled, perturbed
> - uprooted
> - ill at ease
> - uncomfortable, unsettled, out of place, anomic, unstable

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are thinking of ***finding oneself***.

> **find oneself**: "to realize and accept one's real character; discover
>   one's true vocation" —*[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/find-yourself)*

I had thought that this usage was fairly recent, dating perhaps to the early or mid twentieth century, but the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70348) attests to something very similar all the way back to 1642, with a very clearly modern take in the example quote from 1893:

> **find, *v.* II.9.e.** *refl.* To discover and attain one's special place,
>   power, or vocation. ... 1893 *Academy* 11. Mar. 222/1 It was as
>   assistant to Bain that Minto **found himself**.

This usage can carry some pejorative connotations, particularly in the case of someone who was once "settled" but has decided to give that up and go "find him/herself":

> Maybe he left **to find himself**. Maybe he left to look for a 21-year-old
>   *Baywatch* kind of wife. Too many men are running away from their responsibilities because those responsibilities interfere with their
>   insatiable searches for personal pleasure. [—*I'm their Dad! Not their
>   Babysitter!* by Tim Herrera](https://books.google.com/books?id=55CgnaTNBnkC&lpg=PA72&dq=%22left%20to%20find%20himself%22&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q=%22left%20to%20find%20himself%22&f=false)

but is also used more neutrally about (often, but not always, younger) people who are in the process of discovering or actively looking for their place in life:

> "All girls and boys go through phases like Chloe's. At eighteen, she's
>   **still finding herself**." [—*One Flew Under the Cuckoo's Nest* by Ami
>   Amara](https://books.google.com/books?id=zGLsxnIzxOAC&lpg=PA119&dq=%22still%20finding%20herself%22&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=%22still%20finding%20herself%22&f=false)
>
> Michael Rosenberg is a wonderful father. It's as if in finding his children (he has two) unfolding before him at last **he's finding himself**. [—*People Like Ourselves* by Pamela Jooste](https://books.google.com/books?id=BEqv2YUKMisC&lpg=PT18&dq=%22he's%20finding%20himself%22&pg=PT18#v=onepage&q=%22he's%20finding%20himself%22&f=false)
>
> *I found myself walking around asking why I was even living. I was
>   broken and lost, not even sure where I was, but out of this emotional
>   barrenness I knew I had **to find*** me. *And so, I took a journey **to find
>   myself** and begin the process of healing all the broken places.*
>   [—*Finding Sarah: A Duchess's Journey **to Find Herself*** by Sarah Ferguson, Sarah (Duchess of York)](https://books.google.com/books?id=kTrbspUidDYC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22still%20finding%20herself%22&pg=PR13#v=onepage&q=%22still%20finding%20herself%22&f=false), from the letter to readers

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments that state that "settled down" does not necessarily entail all the meaning you have ascribed. In the most general sense, "settled down" means you have a good deal of responsibility and are not free to follow all your whims without consulting other concerned parties, be they your spouse, employer, family, etc. Therefore, consider

**Unfettered** ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfettered))

> *adj.* not controlled or restricted, free, unrestrained

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts go to "up in the air", "undecided", "open". What you want seems to cover quite a wide range of possibilities. I even thought about "disarray", but that's a little too judgemental / negative for what you want, I believe.

From "open" you can move on to "an open book", "a blank page", "a story in the making"...